# Constant Accuracy in CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying train a Vigg19 network with [Fine-Grained Visual Classification of Aircraft](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/data/fgvc-aircraft/) benchmark data set. I chose 3 aircraft family. Using the text files that are given in dataset, I manage to construct a dataframe in order to use flow_from_dataframe generator.

```
df = pd.read_csv("./train_family.csv")
df_test = pd.read_csv("./test_family.csv")

datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.,validation_split=0.25,rotation_range=10, horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True)
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df, 
                                            directory="./data/images", 
                                            x_col="train", y_col="labels", 
                                            class_mode="categorical", target_size=(224,224), batch_size=8, seed = 19, shuffle = True, color_mode = "rgb",
                                            subset = "training")

valid_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df, 
                                            directory="./data/images", 
                                            x_col="train", y_col="labels", 
                                            class_mode="categorical", target_size=(224,224), batch_size=8, seed = 19, shuffle = True, color_mode = "rgb",
                                            subset = "validation")

test_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df_test, 
                                            directory="./data/images", 
                                            x_col="test", y_col="labels", 
                                            class_mode="categorical", target_size=(224,224), batch_size=8, seed = 19, shuffle = False, color_mode = "rgb")
```

While fitting the model, algorithm always gives the same validation accuracy which is "1"

> loss: 5.5803 - acc: 0.6538 - val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - **val_acc: 1.0000**

I did some digging, maybe the problem caused by the amount of data in my train/val/test sets. Below, you can see the output of generator for train, validation and test sets respectively.

```
Found 550 images belonging to 3 classes.
Found 183 images belonging to 3 classes.
Found 367 images belonging to 3 classes.
```

Should I increase the train set by decreasing the test set?

Thanks